# How to import a mixture of CMake and Makefile project to CLion?

Tags: cmake, makefile, clion

We have a PostgreSQL-based project which adds several new C++ plugins under `./contrib` folder. PostgreSQL is built in Makefile, in order to build those newly-added C++ plugins, we just add a task

```
# in contrib/storage_am/Makefile
build-storage-am:
    mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. ${CMAKE_FLAGS} -DBUILD_GTEST=ON -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${prefix} -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PATH=${prefix} && make

# in main Makefile:
all:
    ...
    $(MAKE) -C contrib/storage_am
```

and when importing this project to CLion, it read it as a Makefile project and starts dry-run the task `all`. From the `Build` panel I can see it properly read the Makefile file and executed these tasks using CMake to build these plugins:

[image: CLion Build Syncing]

but all code files using CMake are still unindexed. Is there any way to import these "CMake called by Makefile" project into CLion? would Compilation Database and [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) can solve this. Make sure to clean your Makefile and CMake projects then `bear -- make all` and open the generated `compilation_commands.json` in CLion directly.